# UIActivityViewController completion handler still calls action even if user presses cancel

Tags: ios, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

This is really annoying! Completed is always returned yes even if the user cancels the share option. e.g. I tap on the facebook share and dont share, just tap cancel. Is there a way to track this?

```
[activityVC setCompletionWithItemsHandler:
 ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {

     if (completed)
     {
         [GoogleAnalytics trackShareEvents:activityType];
     }else
     {
         [GoogleAnalytics trackEventWithCategory:@"Share" action:@"Failed/Canceled" eventLabel:activityType];
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Did you ever find anything about this?

Comment: nope. But I haven't checked the new versions of iOS.